# JNI programming : error - Class jni not found

Tags: java-native-interface, runtime-error

An error occur while running this code:

```
$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ javah jni HelloWorld
error: cannot access jni
class file for jni not found
javadoc: error - Class jni not found.
2 errors
```

how could I overcome it?
please give me a solution..
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `javah -jni` instead of `javah jni`.